# Geopandas ImportError: DLL load failed (in pyviz tutorial geographic data examples) win7

Tags: python, geopandas

I'm trying to run the geographic data examples from pyviz tutorial. I'm getting the error list in modules below. My Geopandas module work fine (and the others dependent modules) with 3.5 python version in another project made with pycharm interpreter. I think it could be a python version problem...not sure.

---

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
    ----> 1 import geopandas as gpd
    2 world = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))
    3 world.head()

C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\geopandas__init__.py in 
    3 from geopandas.geodataframe import points_from_xy
    4 
    ----> 5 from geopandas.io.file import read_file
    6 from geopandas.io.sql import read_postgis
    7 from geopandas.tools import sjoin

C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\geopandas\io\file.py in 
    2 from distutils.version import LooseVersion
    3 
    ----> 4 import fiona
    5 import numpy as np
    6

C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\fiona__init__.py in 
   67 from six import string_types
   68 
    ---> 69 from fiona.collection import Collection, BytesCollection, vsi_path
    70 from fiona._drivers import driver_count, GDALEnv
    71 from fiona.drvsupport import supported_drivers

C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\fiona\collection.py in 
    7 
    8 from fiona import compat
    ----> 9 from fiona.ogrext import Iterator, ItemsIterator, KeysIterator
   10 from fiona.ogrext import Session, WritingSession
   11 from fiona.ogrext import (

ImportError: DLL load failed: Impossível localizar o módulo especifica

Comment: How did you install GeoPandas?

Comment: I saw that i have 2 versions off GeoPandas installed in my computer. The first was installed via Conda in conda-force channel (version 0.5.0) and the second installed via pip (version 0.4.0) . The version installed via PIP works fine, but the GeoPandas installed via Conda return the errors reported. The GeoPandas via pip work in python 3.5 version, and the Geopandas via conda run's in python 3.7. Could It be the problem, two version of Geopandas in same computer?

Comment: My error is similar with this: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50490515/import-error-when-importing-geopandas) The solution described solve the error? @joris do you had feedback from this error?